# Github - Cloning Private Repository without SSH keys.

Tags: git, github, repository

Apologises if this is in the wrong forum.

Basically, I have created a Private Repository on my Github account and I am allowing certain members to be collaborators on it. The thing is, I don't want to add SSH keys to my account which would mean they have access to all my Repositories.

Is it possible where I can add them as a collaborator and then can simply use commands:

`git clone [repository] -> git add -> git push` etc..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your stated question (how to clone/push without keys) is, quite simply: you cannot.

But that’s only because it’s based on a misunderstanding: you should not add a collaborator’s keys directly to your own account. Instead, they should create their own account, and then you add them as a collaborator on the repository/repositories you want them to have access to. From the [GitHub Help Site](https://help.github.com/articles/how-do-i-add-a-collaborator):

> Good to know: Collaborators always receive read/write permissions. To
>   grant read-only or admin permissions to a repo, the repo must be owned
>   by an organization.
>
> 1. Visit the repository's page
> 2. Click the "Settings" button
> 3. Click the "Collaborators" tab
> 4. Enter part of the user's login or email
> 5. Select the user from the dropdown
> 6. Click "Add"
>
> Good to know: Before they can be added to a repository, the person
>   must have a GitHub account. If they don't have one, they can sign up
>   on the free plan. Users can always collaborate on private
>   repositories, even on the free plan.

Comment: Can you please extend your answer and explain what the **collaborator** (that is *not* the owner of the repo) has to do on his side? What should he set in his github account and what `git` cloning command should he use?

Comment: @Dror They don’t have to do anything (except have a GitHub account, of course). By being added they can access the repo via its normal URLs.

Comment: Somehow it doesn't work for my collaborator. He has an account, and I added him, but he cannot clone. He gets a some "access denied" error. How merely using the ssh url for instance tells the github system who is the user and is he authorized to clone the pointed repo?

Comment: @Dror Their SSH keys have to be setup with GitHub. If you keep having issues [GitHub’s help site](https://help.github.com/) is useful, and you can always [contact them](https://help.github.com/contact).